# Phone Number Retrieval Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, phone-number

I know this was not possible before, but I was wondering if there was any way possible to programmatically retrieve the device's phone number in the new update. I know that they added a lot of new features regarding your contacts information, but I want to know my own phone number in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are refering to the "Mango" update then no. This information is not available.

There are no public details about what will be available in future updates.